# Error 500 and PHP crash

Tags: php

I have this on the page

```
<section class="sidebar">                    
    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <?php require_once 'includes/left.php'; ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

In this `left.php` I have:

```
<?php 

    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 1){
        echo'                       
             <li class="active">
                  <a href="index.php">
                       <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Home</span>
                  </a>
             </li>
             <li class="treeview">
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                          <span>MainMenu</span>
                      <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.1</a></li>  
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.2</a></li> 
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.3</a></li>  
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.4</a></li> 
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.5</a></li>  
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.6</a></li> 
                   </ul>                            
              </li>                        
              <li class="treeview">
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                       <span>MainMenu2</span>
                       <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                   </a>
                   <ul class="treeview-menu">';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT form.field_name, form.group_id, form.field_id, cat.form_field_cat_name, cat.group_id
                            FROM form_fields form JOIN form_fields_category cat
                            ON form.group_id = cat.group_id
                            WHERE form.group_id = cat.group_id
                            GROUP BY form.group_id "); 
                $sql->execute();
                $rows = $sql->fetchAll();

                $html = [];

                foreach ($rows as $row) {              
                     $html [] = '<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1 "' . $row['form_field_cat_name'] . '"</a></li>';               
                }
                   echo join("", $html); 
                   Database::disconnect();                  
        }   
        elseif ($_SESSION['role'] == 2)
        {
            echo '  
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li> 
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <span>MainMenu</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.3</a></li>  
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.4</a></li> 
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.5</a></li>  
                       <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_1.6</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </li>                      
                <li class="treeview">
                     <a href="#">
                           <i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                           <span>MainMenu2</span>
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="treeview-menu">';
                          $pdo = Database::connect();
                          $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT form.field_name, form.group_id, form.field_id, cat.form_field_cat_name, cat.group_id
                            FROM form_fields form JOIN form_fields_category cat
                            ON form.group_id = cat.group_id
                            WHERE form.group_id = cat.group_id
                            GROUP BY form.group_id "); 

                          $sql->execute();
                          $rows = $sql->fetchAll();

                          $html = [];

                          foreach ($rows as $row) {            
                               $html [] = '<li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Role_2 "' . $row['form_field_cat_name'] . '"</a></li>';             
                          }

                           echo join("", $html); 
                           Database::disconnect();                                                      
        }
```

In this `left.php` I just have 2 menus and based on user role I show which menu is for him/her. The problem is that my host is showing me error 500 when I run the page. And the problem in error log of the hosting is

```
EACCELERATOR: PHP crashed
```

When I remove this `include 'includes/left.php'` page is running normally. Can someone explain me what causes this error? What is wrong in `left.php`?

Comment: I do not see a `session_start()` in your code ANYWHERE

Comment: No error checking for your PDO calls!!!!

Comment: I put `session_start();` at the top but still same.

Comment: ` session_start() ` is missing and also the query runs fine ?

Comment: `WHERE form.group_id = cat.group_id` seems a little unnecessary! Not sure if it is actually enough to crash the query

Comment: On other host and on the localhost where `eaccelerator` isn't Enabled there is no problems.

Comment: The query is fine and is working. Tried it also in phpmyadmin. Something else happen here.

Comment: Well I would look at creating a Staging server with eAccelerator installed as its obviously something to do with that

Comment: Does eaccelerator produce a log file that would give you more information

Comment: No I only see the errors in the cPanel.. `[notice] EACCELERATOR(2874): PHP crashed on opline 12 of main() at /home/.../public_html/index.php:227` . Line 227 is exactly where I include this file

Comment: Its just a guess, but maybe if you changed `$sql->fetchAll();` and did a simple fetch in a while loop, that might be worth a try as its not a huge change. Maybe the cache is getting overloaded by a fetchAll

Comment: It's clearly those two parts with the queries are the problem. I commented them and it is working. What exactly you propose? I can't understand..

Comment: You do a `->fetchAll` which fills a array with a LOT of result rows. Instead of that amend the code to `fetch` one row at a time in a while loop

Comment: Well thank's for that. It fixed it on the index page. Now same thing happen on other page where `left.php` isn't included. So if I understand correctly the problem is in huge query and `EACCELERATOR` can't cache all the data that query return for the X time?